# Background Image displaying in Design view but not in browser? (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and this issue in Visual Studio is driving me mad!

I have a background image defined within a simple style sheet...

```
body {

background-image: url(Images\Greenhouse.jpg);
background-position: center;

}
```

My style sheet is referenced within the HTML code...

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css"/>

</head>
```

The background image shows in design view but in the browser, nothing!

I've tried changing position etc and refreshed the browser, cleared the cache etc. This happens with all my images. Images are within the project folder (\Images) and added to the solution explorer in VS. Tried "", changing image file names etc, nothing is working!

Comment: Should have asked this before posting an answer. Could be a stupid question but: You have added `<body>` tags in your HTML, right?

Comment: Where is the stylesheet file in the folder structure? The `background-image` path must be relative to the stylesheet. Also, try using a forward slash in the path.

Comment: Hi, yes I have <body> tags as standard and the Style SHeet is included in the project (App directory). Ok, now some images are displaying both in design view and browser and others not in either! Could it be to do with file names or something?

Comment: change background-image to background and see if you can get output then, I have had issues with background-image in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I solved this by moving the background image to the root directory and renaming to a shorter file name. Looks like VS didn't like the long image name with underscores. Thanks all.